# Project with openCV won't build because of opencv dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I had build OpenCV from source without any errors.

Then I tried using OpenCV in a project and it won't compile because of the dependencies. All the libraries in the warning are installed but have different versions (actually, no versions' numbers added after .a and .so names).

Here's the compiling errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.53, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.53, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.51, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libswscale.so.2, needed by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

How do I get rid of the errors? And why do they occur?

Compilation command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -gdwarf-3 -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/rankcollection build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/QueryCollection.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lboost_filesystem -lopencv_core -lboost_program_options -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_nonfree -lboost_system -lopencv_highgui -std=c++11
```

Comment: Show your `Makefile` or compilation commands

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -gdwarf-3    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/rankcollection build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/QueryCollection.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lboost_filesystem -lopencv_core -lboost_program_options -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_nonfree -lboost_system -lopencv_highgui -std=c++11

Comment: Not as a comment - it's hard to read. Please click `edit` under your question and update that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading Boost from 1.57 to 1.55 has helped.

But I still have no idea why I had the problem to begin with.